# Custom Route with React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am after creating a custom Route component with React. I came across the following solution I found but I am getting the error after.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../modules/AuthService';

export class AuthRequiredRoute extends Route {
render() {
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
    } else {
        return <this.props.component />
    }
  }
}
```

**Error: JSX element type 'this.props.component' does not have any construct or call signatures.**

Following is the way I am going to use the component:

```
<AuthRequiredRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
```

Can anybody help me with resolving this issue please?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue by going with a different solution.

**I created a HOC module named Authenticated.tsx with the below code:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../modules/AuthService';

export function Authenticated(BaseComponent) {
class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<any>, {}> {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.checkAuthentication(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.location !== this.props.location) {
            this.checkAuthentication(nextProps);
        }
    }

    checkAuthentication(params) {
        const { history } = params;
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            history.replace({ pathname: '/login' });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <BaseComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
}

return withRouter(AuthenticatedComponent);
}
```

**Then I used it this way in my routes.tsx component:**

```
import { Authenticated } from './components/utils/Authenticated';

export const routes = <Layout>
<Route exact path='/' component={Authenticated(Home)} />
<Route path='/login' component={Login} />
</Layout>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the abilities of polymorphism? worked perfect for me:

```
 export class ProtectedRoute extends Route {
   render() {
     if (!isLoggedIn()) {
         return <Redirect to='/login' />
     } else {
       return super.render();
     }
   }
 }
```

In OO concepts(although we are JS world...) the render of Route is a black box and I assume we wont be able to exactly to code the the base render. All we want is to add behavior to A Route element for a specific behavior(not logged in) so all we to add is what we want to extend not the basic  behavior. Furthermore even if for some reason(might say not so smart) I would copy exactly the contents of the basic render of Route. if one day Route would be updated I would lose all those added features.

Comment: Great suggestion Yaakov, would be great to include an explanation of thy the OP's attempt did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Component` variable to construct a jsx component:

```
export class AuthRequiredRoute extends Route {
    render() {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return <Redirect to='/login' />
        } else {
            let Component = this.props.component;
            return <Component />
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but now I am getting the same error on <Component />

Comment: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: What is your `Home` component?

Comment: I have started a project using the standard Visual Studio 2017 ASP .Net Core SPA project template which contains a boot.tsx and routes.tsx. Here is my Home.tsx

Comment: import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

export class Home extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        </div>;
    }
}

Comment: This is the routes.tsx

Comment: import * as React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';
import { Home } from './components/Home';
import { Login } from './components/Login';
import { AuthRequiredRoute } from './components/utils/AuthRequiredRoute'

export const routes = <Layout>
    <AuthRequiredRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
</Layout>;

Comment: The initial component is a boot.tsx which I will split it in 3 comments bellow:

Comment: import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
let routes = RoutesModule.routes;

Comment: function renderApp() {
    // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing
    // configuration and injects the app into a DOM element.
    const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <BrowserRouter children={routes} basename={baseUrl} />
        </AppContainer>,
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
}

renderApp();

Comment: // Allow Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
        routes = require<typeof RoutesModule>('./routes').routes;
        renderApp();
    });
}